# How to add picture to a SharePoint list?

Tags: list, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008. I want to add a list with two columns, one column displays picture, and the other column displayes rich text.

I did not find a way to display picture itself into a list (picture type column of list seems only add a link of picture to the column, not the picture itself). Any ideas how to implement? And is it possible to implement paging on list -- e.g. display 20 items on each page, and if 100 items, display by 5 pages (end user could use page-up and page-down to control paged view)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about SharePoint lists when you say you want to create a list and not that you want to create your own custom list control..

The column type "Image with formatting and constraints for publishing" has a thumbnail preview in list views, the standard Image column type does not, I suspect you are using the one from WSS instead of the one that comes with the Publishing feature in MOSS.

List views also come with paging automatically, I think the default is about 20? But if you drop down on the view menu and click modify this view, you will be able to specify the item limit. Paging is done using two (very small and somewhat hard to find sometimes) arrows that usually appear in a blue bar underneath the listview and sometimes in the top right of the list view.

Comment: "I assume you are talking about SharePoint lists when you say you want to create a list" -- yes.

Comment: column type "Image with formatting and constraints for publishing" -- where can I find the column type? I did not find such column type when I create a list and select data sheet view? Appreciate if you could let me know where to find the column type you mentioned?

Comment: "I suspect you are using the one from WSS instead of the one that comes with the Publishing feature in MOSS." -- maybe, I am using MOSS 2007. Appreciate if you could let me know how to find the column type (Image with formatting and constraints for publishing) you mentioned. :-)

Comment: You need to add a new column to your list, as you stated you are using the Publishing Portal Template that means you will have the additional column types that support publishing sites. So, create a new column and in the list of possible column types you will see the "Image with formatting and constraints for publishing". However, you mentioned using the datasheet view, is this something you need to use? Because I am quite certain that this will not render the image even when using the above column type. Standard list views will.

Comment: Cool, question answered!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Content Type with the Picture Content Type as a parent and create a site column for your rich text field. Then you can create a picture library and select to manage the Content Types and change it to your new custom content type and select the fields that you want.

This way, you will be able to create a view of your list with the picture (that will be uploaded as the item is created) and your rich text field. You can also customize this view to page as you prefer. I don't know a way to be able to use the page up/down control, but you can use a jQuery script that can modify the size of the paging commands so that they will be easier to see and use.

Comment: "content type with the Picture content type as a parent" -- can you show me how?

Comment: Go into Site Actions>Site Settings and click on Site content type under Galleries. Click on Create. Title your new content type something you will remember and select Document Content Types as the type to select from and Picture as the parent. Click OK.

Comment: When the content type opens, click on Add from new site column under Columns. Title your column what you want it to be, then select Multiple lines of text. Set up your column with the properties you choose (allow hyperlinks, tables, etc..) and click OK. Create a new picture library. Go into the picture library settings and click on Advanced Settings. Select to allow management of content types. Then under content types in the library settings, select Add from existing and select your new content type. Then change it to be the default and click on the original content type and delete it.

Comment: Now you can go into your custom content type and adjust the columns to display the rich text field site column you created. Now you just need to set a view that only shows those two columns and you will have your list.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to add a calculated column that renders some html, for example an img tag with a src attribute that references the values of another field on your list.